# Shortest Path Given some Edges Cannot be used

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path

Given an n by m Matrix, if we are trying to get from the bottom left cell to the top right cell (so from (0,0) to (n,m)) is there an algorithm to calculate the shortest path if we cannot traverse edges that have a cost greater than k > 0?

Comment: I imagine a simple implementation of [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) will get the job done.

Comment: Any normal shortest path algorithm should work. Just ignore the edges which cannot be traversed.